# Laravel 5.5 manage relations between packages

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am planning to split the project into multiple packages:

**Products**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

**Articles**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

**Images**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'imageable');
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Article::class, 'imageable');
}
```

Everything works fine but in the future I will probably add more packages that will morph to the Image model so I will add the relation to it.

The problem comes if I want to add the reverse relations into the Image model which is a dependency for the other modules.

I am trying to find a clean way for doing this without updating the Images module each time I am adding a new module that morphs to it.

The same problem appears if I want to add more scope methods, repository methods etc.

I can extend them inside the core project but I have to create another service provider etc. so keeping the modules in external packages would become helpless.

Comment: By packages you mean `composer` packages? I would recommend not having any relationships on your `Image` class. Instead keep that package completely independent, but within your app, add your own class which extends it and adds those relationships